# Roulette Probability - Occurence of the Same Value

Tags: probability

In a game of roulette four rolls the number 9 came up three spins in a row. What are the odds of this happening?

My attempt: (1/38)^3(37/38) (the event happening three times and then something else happening once).  Is this right?

Comment: There are unfortunately several possible interpretations: does it mean exactly $3$ times, or at least $3$ times? Even if exactly $3$, I think N999 and 999N both qualify, so need to double to get the *probability*.

Comment: Exactly 3 times

Comment: Another way to do it is to divide the possible number of ways this can happen by the total number of possible outcomes. There are $38^4$ total possible outcomes and one can get three $9$'s by getting first any of 37 other numbers and then three $9$'s, or three $9$'s and then any of 37 other numbers, so there are $2\cdot37$ possible ways for this to happen. Thus, you have $2\cdot 37 / 38^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we played roulette $4$ times. We  tell a friend that $9$ came up exactly $3$ times in a row when we played.

We could mean that we got one of the two  patterns $999N$ or $N999$, where $N$ ranges over the non-$9$s. Under this quite reasonable interpretation,  your  $(1/38)^3(37/38)$ should be multiplied by $2$.

**Remark:** There is a further complication. The question asks for the *odds*. That term, among gamblers at least, does not mean probability. If $p$ is the probability of our event, then a gambler would say that the odds are $p:1-p$.

Comment: Could the combination N999N also come up?  I understand yours to mean the three happen at the beginning or end.

Comment: The problem may not be quoted quite correctly, but it says explicitly $4$ rolls, which I assume means spins of the wheel. If there were exactly $4$ rolls, then $N999N'$ is automatically ruled out.